# Returning unique values from embedded loop

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet 5 and writing a module which refers to some hiera which has some duplication in it (example below - see gpgkey):

```
profile::example1:
  repo1:
    descr: Centos repo 
    gpgkey: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
  repo2:
    descr: Centos repo
    gpgkey: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
  repo3:
    descr: puppet repo
    gpgkey: http://puppet.repo/GPG-KEY
```

I've successfully managed to retrieve the repo names (repo1, repo2 and repo3 in this example). What I'd like to do next is run an exec to import the gpgkey, however this is failing with a duplicate declaration error (I assume because the gpgkey is duplicated in the hiera). Any ideas or help on how to do this? Here's the lookup:

```
  $repo_name = lookup('profile::example1', Hash, 'deep')
        $repo_name.each | $name, Hash $config_hash | {
        notify { "${name}": }
  }
```

I've looked at embedding another loop to pull values from $config_hash but I usually get the same result regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puppet's built-in [`unique()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#unique) function seems natural for this job.  For example:

```
$repos = lookup('profile::example1', Hash, 'deep')
$unique_keys = $repos.map |$_name, $props| { $props['gpgkey'] } .unique
$unique_keys.each |$key| {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, I'm getting an empty string error now: "Server Error: Evaluation Error: Empty string title at 0. Title strings must have a length greater than zero." Any immediate thoughts.

Comment: @user3229731, First guess: one of your repos does not have a gpgkey declared for it in your data.  If something along those lines is the problem then you can use the `filter` function to take the resulting empty string(s) out of consideration.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I've actually gone for an alternate route but the code above is useful.